# Bootstrapping multiple regression error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, linear-regression, bootstrapping

I want to bootstrap my dataset for multiple regression. Unfortunately I get this error message:

```
    "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"
```

I suspect that the factors in my regression formula may be problematic.

What could I do to solve my problem?

My code is as following (I read Andy Field´s Discovering Statistics using R):

```
    BootReg <- function(data,  indices, formula) {
      d <- data[indices,] 
      fit <- lm(formula, data=d) 
      return(coef(fit)) 
      }

    bootResults <-boot(statistic = BootReg, formula = TICS_Skala1 ~HSPhoch + HSPhoch*extra.c     
    + psy + sex + age.c, data = mod.reg.data, R = 2000)
```

psy (psychiatric disease), sex and HSPhoch (high sensory-processing sensitivity) are factors. TICS_Skala1, extra.c, age.c are continuos variables.

my sample data:

```
> dput(head(mod.reg.data, 20))
structure(list(neo_01 = c(3, 4, 3, 0, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 
3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2), neo_03 = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1), neo_04 = c(2, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 
4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3), neo_08 = c(3, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1), neo_12 = c(3, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2), neo_13 = c(3, 
2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2), neo_16 = c(3, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1), neo_17 = c(2, 
1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2), neo_18 = c(2, 
3, 4, 0, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2), neo_21 = c(3, 
0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1), neo_26 = c(3, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1), neo_27 = c(3, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2), TICS_1 = c(3, 
0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2), TICS_2 = c(3, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1), TICS_3 = c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), TICS_4 = c(2, 
0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), TICS_5 = c(2, 
3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), TICS_6 = c(3, 
2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), TICS_7 = c(3, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1), TICS_8 =c(NA,  
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 
2), TICS_9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2), TICS_10 = c(2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), TICS_11 = c(1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), TICS_12 = c(2, 
2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3), TICS_13=  
c(1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
TICS_14= c(4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1,  
1), TICS_15= c(3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1), ICS_16= c(4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3,  
1, 2, 1), TICS_17= c(3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3,  
1, 1, 1, 2), TICS_18= c(3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0,  
0, 1, 0, 2, 0), TICS_19= c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2,  
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2), TICS_20= c(2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1,  
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0), TICS_21= c(2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0), TICS_22= c(3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3), TICS_24= c(2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), TICS_25= c(4, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 
1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1), TICS_26= c(3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), TICS_27= c(3, 
1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3), TICS_28=  
c(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2), 
TICS_29= c(2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1), TICS_30= c(2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
2, 2), TICS_31= c(2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 1), TICS_32= c(4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3), TICS_33= c(2, 
1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), TICS_34= 
c(1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),  
TICS_35= c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 
1), TICS_36= c(4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
2, 1), TICS_37= c(1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 1), TICS_38= c(3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2), TICS_39= c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 0, 0, 3), TICS_40= c(2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1), TICS_41= c(2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0), TICS_42= c(1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TICS_43= c(4, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3), TICS_44= 
c(3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1), 
TICS_45= c(2, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), TICS_46= 
c(2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
TICS_47= c(3, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1), TICS_48= 
c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0), TICS_49= 
c(1, 
3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0, 3), TICS_50= 
c(3, 
0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), TICS_51= 
c(1, 
2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TICS_52= 
c(2, 
1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), TICS_53= 
c(2, 
2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), TICS_54= 
c(3, 
0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1), TICS_55= 
c(2, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0), TICS_56= 
c(4, 
3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), TICS_57= 
c(2, 
1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2), HSPS_1 = 
c(3, 
4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2), HSPS_2 = 
c(4, 
4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3), HSPS_3 = 
c(4, 
4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2), HSPS_4 = 
c(4, 
2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2), HSPS_5 = 
c(2, 
2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1), HSPS_6 = 
c(4, 
3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2), HSPS_7 = 
c(4, 
3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1), HSPS_8 = 
c(4, 
3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), HSPS_9 = 
c(3, 
2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2), HSPS_10= 
c(4, 
4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2), HSPS_11= 
c(3, 
2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), HSPS_12= 
c(4, 
4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4), HSPS_13= 
c(3, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2), HSPS_14= 
c(3, 
 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2), HSPS_15= 
 c(4, 
 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2), HSPS_16= 
 c(2, 
2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2), HSPS_17= 
c(4, 
3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4), HSPS_18= 
c(2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1), HSPS_19= 
c(3, 
2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2), HSPS_20= 
 c(4, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2), HSPS_21= 
c(3, 
3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2), HSPS_22= 
c(3, 
5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2), HSPS_23= 
c(2, 
2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3), HSPS_24= 
c(3, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2), HSPS_25= 
c(3, 
2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2), HSPS_26= 
c(2, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2), HSPS_27= 
c(2, 
2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3), sex =    
structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("m", "w", "d"), class = "factor"), Bildung =  
structure(c(6L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("kein", "Haupt", "mittlereR", "Fachabi", 
"Abi", "Studium"), class = "factor"), job = structure(c(6L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 6L), .Label = c("hausl", "Student", "Azubi", "Suchend", "Rente", 
"berufstaetig"), class = "factor"), age = c(23, 24, 21, 70, 25, 
29, 22, 25, 57, 24, 25, 30, 31, 20, 28, 27, 26, 21, 24, 53), 
VPN = 1:20, consent = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label =  
 c("ja", 
"nein"), class = "factor"), psy = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), HSPS = c(86, 75, 
69, 102, 85, 82, 97, 59, 100, 68, 80, 106, 68, 73, 105, 79, 
91, 63, 119, 59), neuro = c(16, 3, 4, 10, 10, 11, 12, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 16, 5, 18, 4, 3, 8, 5, 19, 7), extra = c(15, 17, 
19, 7, 19, 17, 18, 17, 16, 10, 17, 14, 15, 19, 11, 13, 16, 
18, 9, 13), TICS_Skala1 = c(23, 1, 22, 11, 14, 16, 22, 25, 
2, 11, 1, 29, 9, 20, 10, 19, 16, 9, 18, 16), TICS_Skala2 = c(14, 
12, 11, 9, 11, 10, 4, 10, 5, 8, 5, 24, 13, 5, 6, 6, 14, 2, 
1, 13), TICS_Skala3 = c(21, 6, 10, 5, 12, 14, 11, 20, 3, 
11, 4, 27, 20, 13, 7, 13, 20, 11, 11, 18), TICS_Skala4 = c(13, 
14, 13, 2, 16, 23, 10, 9, 3, 13, 15, 18, 14, 11, 13, 10, 
7, 9, 17, 6), TICS_Skala5 = c(12, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 3, 4, 
6, 0, 18, 3, 7, 1, 6, 6, 1, 13, 3), TICS_Skala6 = c(10, 2, 
3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5, 2, 15, 10, 5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 8, 3), 
TICS_Skala7 = c(15, 5, 9, 13, 4, 8, 4, 9, 1, 6, 2, 11, 2, 
12, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 7), TICS_Skala8 = c(8, 10, 3, 0, 11, 7, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 7, 20, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3), TICS_Skala9 = c(12, 
3, 4, 8, 8, 6, 9, 5, 2, 6, 5, 11, 3, 11, 1, 5, 9, 3, 7, 5
), TICS_Skala10 = c(32, 5, 18, 16, 19, 18, 21, 16, 5, 17, 
7, 39, 12, 24, 3, 15, 20, 6, 25, 14), neuro.c = c(6.08921933085502, 
-6.91078066914498, -5.91078066914498, 0.089219330855018, 
0.089219330855018, 1.08921933085502, 2.08921933085502,  
-4.91078066914498, 
-4.91078066914498, -4.91078066914498, -4.91078066914498, 
 6.08921933085502, -4.91078066914498, 8.08921933085502, 
-5.91078066914498, 
-6.91078066914498, -1.91078066914498, -4.91078066914498, 
9.08921933085502, -2.91078066914498), extra.c = c(5.21003717472119, 
7.21003717472119, 9.21003717472119, -2.78996282527881, 
9.21003717472119, 
7.21003717472119, 8.21003717472119, 7.21003717472119, 
  6.21003717472119, 
  0.21003717472119, 7.21003717472119, 4.21003717472119, 
  5.21003717472119, 
  9.21003717472119, 1.21003717472119, 3.21003717472119, 
  6.21003717472119, 
  8.21003717472119, -0.78996282527881, 3.21003717472119), age.c = 
  c(-15.4460966542751, 
  -14.4460966542751, -17.4460966542751, 31.5539033457249,   
  -13.4460966542751, 
  -9.4460966542751, -16.4460966542751, -13.4460966542751, 
  18.5539033457249, 
 -14.4460966542751, -13.4460966542751, -8.4460966542751, 
 -7.4460966542751, 
 -18.4460966542751, -10.4460966542751, -11.4460966542751, 
 -12.4460966542751, -17.4460966542751, -14.4460966542751, 
 14.5539033457249), HSP.c = c(-1.92936802973978, -12.9293680297398, 
-18.9293680297398, 14.0706319702602, -2.92936802973978, 
 -5.92936802973978, 
 9.07063197026022, -28.9293680297398, 12.0706319702602, 
 -19.9293680297398, 
 -7.92936802973978, 18.0706319702602, -19.9293680297398, 
 -14.9293680297398, 
 17.0706319702602, -8.92936802973978, 3.07063197026022,  
 -24.9293680297398, 
 31.0706319702602, -28.9293680297398), HSPhoch = c(1, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = 
 c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(mod.reg.data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mod.reg.data, 20))`. Also, that is not multiple regression, you have only one response.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, if you google "multiple regression" you'll find that the top results are for a single response variable. Regression with many response variables is often called "multivariate". Of course, no hard and fast rules either way; but I wouldn't beat anyone over the head for preferring one over the other

Comment: @RuiBarradas, it´s still a huge output. But I hope that this sample data can be useful nevertheless

Comment: Thanks for the data. I cannot reproduce the error, and there is nothing wrong with the function. Maybe when bootstrapping the factors some levels are not in the bootstrap sample. Try placing `cat("length coef:", length(coef(fit)), "\n")` right before the `return` instruction and see if the coefs always have the same length.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, somehow Rstudio doesn`t accept this code.      
         ´error: unexpexted token: "  fit <- lm(formula, data=d) 
          cat("length coef:", length(coef(fit)), "\n")return"´

Comment: I am talking about putting the `cat()` instruction in a code line of its own.